# Filling in Dataframe given one column and one row as coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a partially empty dataframe such as:

```
col1   col2  col3  col4  col5
                           4
                           3
                           2
                           1
  4      3     2     1     0
```

I'd like to fill in the empty cells with a list as coordinates such as:

```
col1   col2  col3  col4  col5
[4,4]  [3,4] [2,4] [1,4]  4
[4,3]  [3,3] [2,3] [1,3]  3
[4,2]  [3,2] [2,2] [1,2]  2
[4,1]  [3,1] [2,1] [1,1]  1
  4      3     2     1    0
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `bfill` with `axis`=0 and 1 , then add it up and `fillna`

```
df = df.fillna(df.bfill().applymap(lambda x : [x]) + df.bfill(1).applymap(lambda x : [x]))
Out[431]: 
         col1        col2        col3        col4  col5
0  [4.0, 4.0]  [3.0, 4.0]  [2.0, 4.0]  [1.0, 4.0]     4
1  [4.0, 3.0]  [3.0, 3.0]  [2.0, 3.0]  [1.0, 3.0]     3
2  [4.0, 2.0]  [3.0, 2.0]  [2.0, 2.0]  [1.0, 2.0]     2
3  [4.0, 1.0]  [3.0, 1.0]  [2.0, 1.0]  [1.0, 1.0]     1
4           4           3           2           1     0
```